# How to pass each value of the column from a table to a stored procedure and save the result in a table in SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with username field as given below. I have a stored procedure which receives the username argument and process to show the results. At the moment I am manually executing the stored procedure for each username by specifying the argument and after execution copy paste its result in excel.
The table with username is:

```
╔════╦══════════╦══╗
║ ID ║ Username ║  ║
╠════╬══════════╬══╣
║  1 ║ abc      ║  ║
║  2 ║ def      ║  ║
║  3 ║ ghi      ║  ║
║  4 ║ jkl      ║  ║
║  5 ║ mno      ║  ║
║  6 ║ xyz      ║  ║
╚════╩══════════╩══╝
```

The stored procedure is:

```
spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername 'abc'
```

Its output of the stored procedure is:

```
╔════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ Username ║ Value ║
╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ abc      ║   100 ║
╚════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

I can make a parent stored procedure which contains all the stored procedure and execute it to get the results but I will still have to copy paste the results. E.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPparent
AS
BEGIN
spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername 'abc'
spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername 'def'
spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername 'ghi'
spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername 'jkl'
.
.
.
END
```

I am wondering if it will be possible to get the username and paste the output to a result table automatically.

The desired Result table

```
╔════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ Username ║ Value ║
╠════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ abc      ║   100 ║
║  2 ║ def      ║   200 ║
║  3 ║ ghi      ║   150 ║
║  4 ║ jkl      ║   300 ║
║  5 ║ mno      ║   700 ║
║  6 ║ xyz      ║  1000 ║
╚════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use a cursor for that.

Comment: Ideally, transform the stored procedure into a User Defined Function - then you can call it directly from the original query which gets the usernames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here's a much shorter set-oriented solution that uses no loops or cursors:

```
CREATE TABLE #Results(ID INT, Username SYSNAME, Value INT);
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
INSERT #Results EXEC spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername N'''+Username+''';'
FROM <yourTable>;
EXEC(@sql);

Select * from #Results;
```

Comment: Of course, the drawback here is that it may not produce [exactly the expected results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx): "Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur. This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once for each output row"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It is unclear from the article you reference which versions of SQL Server are effected by the problem of multiple outputs (especially as the KB Article it points to for explanation appears to be mis-linked to an unrelated article), but in any event, changing the last line in my answer above to a `SELECT DISTINCT` would fix that.

Comment: @RBarry, your approach in my case is giving error. The error is Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spA3ForFindingTheNumberOfDaysandPlacesFromFirstDateToLastUpdate, Line 33
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested. Any tweak?

Comment: I have checked and this caveat does not appear to apply to SQL Server 2008, nor any version earlier than 2012.

Comment: @nimko Ah, that will be because your stored procedure `spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername` is *also* using an `INSERT ... EXEC` inside of it.  You cannot nest these, so you will have to rewrite that procedure.  Note that this problem will apply to all of the other solutions as well, as there's no other way to get the output rowset of a stored procedure into your own rowset. I would suggest copying the procedure and rewriting it as a table-valued function instead (which would make all of this trivially easy).

Comment: Do you mean that unless I remove the `INSERT ... EXEC` statement from the existing procedure, I will not be able to capture the result of the procedure. For example @Rachel query is generating the result for all the users so is it not possible to save it in a table or csv?

Comment: @Nimko, Right, you will not be able to capture the output in T-SQL (you can still/always capture the output from a client-side program though).  There's just no way for T-SQL to capture it.  and if T-SQL cannot capture it, then there's no way to combine it into a single table on the server-side.

Comment: Okay thank. just learned that :) Can you please elaborate 'you can still/always capture the output from a client-side program though'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90034/discussion-between-nimko-and-rbarryyoung).

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @UserName NVarChar(128);

Create Table #Results(Id Int, UserName NVarChar(128), Value Int);

Declare curSO Cursor Local
    Fast_Forward
    Read_Only
        For
            Select UserName
              From mySchema.myTable
;

Open curSO;

Fetch Next From curSO
    Into @UserName;

While @@Fetch_Status = 0
Begin

    Insert Into #Results
    Exec spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername @UserName;

    Fetch Next From curSO
        Into @UserName;
End

Close curSO;

Deallocate curSO;

-- Or do something different here. I used a temporary table. You can use whatever
Select *
From #Results
```

Comment: Your approach is working fine for part 1 but part 2 is missing :( That is to store the results in a table otherwise I have to copy paste for 200 times.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be something like this -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPparent
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @id INT, @UserName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (id INT,UserName VARCHAR(100),Value INT)
DECLARE sample_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT ID,UserName
FROM <yourtable>

OPEN sample_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM sample_cursor 
INTO @id, @UserName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TempTable
    Exec spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername @UserName

FETCH NEXT FROM sample_cursor 
INTO @id, @UserName

END

CLOSE sample_cursor

SELECT id,UserName,Value FROM @TempTable

END
```

So here you loop through the initial records from your table and call the sp `spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername` for all the UserName and store them in a temp table. Once done you just select the temp table to get all the records in a table format.

Comment: Got error, Line 46
An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

Comment: @Nimko - just read the discussion ahead. A restriction in SQL Server is you can only have one INSERT-EXEC active at a time, so this will fail. As suggested by @ RBarryYoung you can rewrite the SP to TVF which will solve his. A good read anyways - [link](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using `while` loop like this.

```
DECLARE @id INT, @UserName VARCHAR(100)

SELECT TOP (1) @id = id ,@UserName = UserName
FROM myTable;

WHILE @@rowcount > 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'Exec spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername @UserName;'
        ,N'@UserName VARCHAR(100)'
        ,@UserName = @UserName;

    SELECT TOP (1) @id = id ,@UserName = UserName
    FROM myTable
    WHERE id > @id;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername AS RETURN
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername (
    @Username varchar(255)
) 
AS
    SELECT @Username, 0
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spParent AS RETURN
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE spParent AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @t AS table (id int IDENTITY(1,1), Username varchar(255), Value int)
    DECLARE @num int = 0
    DECLARE @Username varchar(255)
    DECLARE @ret int = 1

    -- DROP TABLE #Users
    CREATE TABLE #Users (
        id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        Username varchar(255) NOT NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO #Users (Username)
    SELECT UserName FROM (VALUES ('abc'), ('def'), ('ghi')) AS t (UserName)

    WHILE @ret > 0
    BEGIN
        IF @UserName IS NOT NULL
            INSERT INTO @t (Username, Value)
            EXEC sp_executesql N'Exec spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername @Username;', '@Username varchar(255)', @Username = @Username;

        SELECT TOP(1) @Username = UserName, @num = id FROM #Users WHERE id > @num ORDER BY id ASC
        SET @ret = @@ROWCOUNT
    END
    SELECT * FROM @t
END
GO

EXEC spParent
GO

DROP PROCEDURE spParent
GO
DROP PROCEDURE spCalculateSomeValuesForThePassedUsername
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```